# Android-rest-ListView

Tags: android, rest

ANdroid - Servicios Rest
Necesito invocar un servicio rest despues de dar click en un registro de la ListView. La aplicacion se reinicia sin marcar error. Si este evento lo manejo desde un boton consume correctamente el servicio. Me pueden ayudar a ver que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, no lo logro identificar que es !!

```
    public ListView epclist;
    onCreate
   .
   .
   epclist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3)
      {
       buscarTag(arg1,"2DEC14DC6496B100000000E3");
      }
    });
    .
    .
    end onCreate

   public void buscarTag(View view,String tag) {

    String url = String.format("http://192.168.1.66:9090/miservicio/rest/rfid/getTickets/2DEC14DC6496B100000000E3");

    new LoadFilmTask().execute(url);

    }

   private class LoadFilmTask extends AsyncTask<String, Long, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            return HttpRequest.get(urls[0]).accept("application/json")
                    .body();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        respuesta =response;
     }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Te marca algún error? ¿Podrías colocar lo que muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: Creo que es mejor que agregues toda tu clase, hay varios detalles que revisar que no se ven en el código que presentas.

Answer (score 0):

Mejor utiliza **Thread** ..  envía la peticion dentro de un hilo..este puede ser tu problema ..de que aveces la red es lenta ..por lo tanto Android no puede esperar mucho tiempo y cierra la aplicacion

```
     Thread thread= new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            >...aqui tu peticion HTTP
        }
    };thread.start();
```